# Image Array swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

Im trying to use image literal in array but when i call them with variables or button it didn't work . I did the same with udemy tutorial and the version in tut works fine but my version stuck in image 0 and not changing even with var .

Code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView2: UIImageView!

    var leftDiceNumber = 0
    var rightDiceNumber = 5


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        diceImageView1.image = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceOne"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceTwo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceThree"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFour"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFive"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceSix")][leftDiceNumber]

        leftDiceNumber = leftDiceNumber + 1

        diceImageView2.image = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceOne"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceTwo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceThree"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFour"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFive"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceSix")][rightDiceNumber]

        rightDiceNumber = rightDiceNumber - 1
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you attached the `@IBAction` to your button?

Comment: Check the button action not connected properly.